# Comparing times from two separate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two separate dataframes with time data. I want to sum the payments to each person for the ad date. Here is the example dataset:

```
Name        Ad Date     Ad Number      
---------------------------------
Michael    4/08/2018        1    
Tony       4/08/2018        1
Alex       4/08/2018        1
Alex       6/08/2018        2
Vanessa    9/08/2018        1

Name        Date         Payments  
--------------------------------------
Michael    4/08/2018      100
Tony       4/08/2018      200
Alex       4/06/2018      300
Alex       6/06/2018      400
Alex       6/07/2018      400
Vanessa    9/08/2018      500
```

Here is the desired output:

```
Name        Ad Number     Payments    
------------------------------------
Michael        1           100
Tony           1           200 
Alex           1           300
Alex           2           800
Vanessa        1           500
```

So if you take a look at Alex, a total of 3 payments were made for 2 ads. I want to sum the payments by using the date range of the ads.

Comment: The data doesn't match between your inputs and outputs for `Alex`. Which date(s) are you intending to use between the two dataframes?

Comment: I am looking at the ad date, so I want to calculate all the payments made before that ad date. Alex has made two ads on two seperate dates. So I want to calculate all the payments made before the first ad for the first ad, and all the payments made after the first ad but before the second ad for the second ad.

Comment: I've edited the frame to clarify

Comment: I've tried joining and aggregating the data, but it begins duplicating the payment values for each ad date

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be the most robust solution it was what I came up with...

```
#Merge two lists
df_new = df.merge(df1,how='outer',on='Name')

#logic to make sure the sum is between the current date and after the previous date
count = 0
temp_list = []
while count != len(df_new): 
  names = df_new.Name[count]
  find = df_new[['Name','Ad Number','Ad Date_x','Ad Date_y','Payments']] [(df_new['Name'] == names)]
  find['new_col'] = np.where(find['Ad Date_y']<=find['Ad Date_x'], 'yes', 'no')
  x = find.sort_values('Ad Date_y')
  x = x[x.new_col == 'yes']
  x = x.drop_duplicates('Ad Date_y')
  x = x.groupby(['Name','Ad Number','Ad Date_x'],as_index=False)['Payments'].sum()
  intermediate_list = x.values.tolist()
  temp_list.append(intermediate_list)
  count += 1

#Traversing through list of lists and appending to final list to make another df
final_list = []
for i in temp_list:
  for j in i:
    final_list.append(j)

#create final df and drop duplicates and drop the Ad_Date Columns
final_df = pd.DataFrame(final_list, columns = ['Name','Ad_Number','Ad_Date','Payments'])
final_df = final_df.drop_duplicates(['Name','Ad_Number','Ad_Date','Payments'])
final_df = final_df.drop('Ad_Date',axis=1)

print(final_df)

#RESULT

Name      Ad_Number  Payments
Michael           1       100
Tony              1       200
Alex              1       300
Alex              2       800
Vanessa           1       500
```